# Реально ли вывести 2 видео в одном окне?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webrtc

Стала передомной задача взаимодействовать web-camery пользователя с 3D моделью.
Взаимодействие заключается в определении положения головы пользователя относительно окна и запуск определённой анимации модели.
Ситуация такая, что если я подключаю модель после камеры, то видно только модель.
Если я подключаю камеру после модели, то видно только картинку, которая берется с камеры.

Можно ли как то сделать, что бы на одной странице одновременно работала и камера, и 3D модель?
Как это сделать, что почитать?

Comment: Наложить сцену с моделью поверх видео с камеры, в настройках рендерера установить прозрачность: `var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({transparent: true}); renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);`. Это навскидку. Хорошо бы показать рабочий пример кода где-нибудь на jsfiddle или codepen. Это чтобы разговаривать более предметно.

Comment: Это понятно, я так и пытался сделать.Только сама картинка камеры не выводится. Модель не закрывает её, а якобы заменяет как я понял. Элементы для выводя используются разные.

Comment: Тогда с вас - простенький пример (jsfiddle.net, codepen.io) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня под рукой веб-камеры нет, но! есть примеры с официального сайта Three.js. Видео вообще: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_materials_video, и видео с веб-камеры: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_materials_video_webcam. И там, и там используется html-элемент `video`, который используется для создания видео-текстуры.

У объекта сцены есть свойство `.background`, которое может быть либо цветом (`THREE.Color()`), либо текстурой (`THREE.Texture()`), либо кубической текстурой (`THREE.CubeTexture()`).

Есть еще такой тип текстуры как `THREE.VideoTexture()` - отличается от обычной текстуры только тем, что постоянно выставляет свой флаг `.needsUpdate` в `true`. Ничто не мешает тогда подставить видео в качестве фона в сцену:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(20, 20));
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(sphere);

video.volume = 0.125;

var vidTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
scene.background = vidTexture;

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  time += clock.getDelta();
  sphere.position.x = Math.cos(time) * 5;
  sphere.position.z = Math.sin(time) * 5;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay loop crossOrigin="anonymous" webkit-playsinline style="display:none" volume="0.5">
   <source src="https://threejs.org/examples/textures/sintel.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
   <source src="https://threejs.org/examples/textures/sintel.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

Вопрос: приемлем ли такой подход?

Comment: Это то, что было мне нужно. Огромное спасибо) Только теперь стаёт проблема как сделать снимок того, что получилось. Так не работает var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); Пустое изображение получается

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - пометьте его как "принятый" (галка под счетчиком плюсов-минусов у ответа). По поводу снимка сцены - лучше создать отдельный вопрос :)

Comment: Спасибо, со всем разобрался)

Comment: @detriat Рад помочь :)